# Getting survey data into predefined database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, cad, autodesk

I have some simple survey data for water lines that will be used to populate a predefined attribute table. I am a surveyor, not a GIS professional, and we have been asked by a client to deliver our survey data in a specific manner.  I do not know how to bring my data into their database so that it matches their format. I have the ArcGIS add on for Autodesk but I'm finding that is more for working with GIS data in CAD and less for prepping CAD files for GIS. At least I am not getting it.

Comment: How are the attributes stored? CAD files can be imported into ArcGIS using Import From CAD https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000024000000 but bringing the attributes into their predefined table may not be a trivial matter. I am assuming that your CAD is at least in a known coordinate reference system and not some sort of local datum, if you're using a local datum that is yet another annoyance that needs to be solved. ArcGIS doesn't do 3d too well, CAD 3d features are converted to 2.5d (geometry 2d with an elevation attribute).

Comment: Sounds like you need to push data into a geodatabase with subtypes and domains set. There is software out there to do this. Can you give a small example of the data you have? AutoCAD would be layers with linewidth and colours but is it spatial referenced?